# using TSQL to "minify" javascript code?

Tags: javascript, t-sql, minify

This may seem like an unusual request, but does anyone have T-SQL (MSSQL2008) code to "minify" javascript code?

I have a MVC site that uses a series of stored procs to generate the contents of a *.js file, and preferably after the SPs built the javascript, it could use a UDF/SP to 'minify' it. 
I thought about creating a second SP set that would contain the minified version, but that would be a maintainance nightmare (doubling the current 10 SP's that build the javascript code).

I didn't know if the logic used to minify was simple enough that an SP/UDF could do it, and if lucky someone had already written it and was willing to share :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 30min later? no one? i've never stumped stackoverflow before :)

Comment: But... why would you possibly need to build javascript files in SQL?

Comment: we have customers that have a script tag on their website that makes calls to our site, which uses these SP's to generate the javascript. the javascript is very specific to each customer.  We chose to create the javascript in SP's for maintainability, so we didn't have to do releases to make changes to the script.  Anyway, the algorithm of minifying can't be THAT complicated, and instead of reinventing the wheel, i thought i'd ask you guys for help.

Comment: @Losbear, but of course! How can a full blown JS interpreter/compiler be complicated, right?

Comment: oh comeon, change variables to one letter names, remove all linebreaks, unnecessary spaces, and you've got the makings of a minifier ;) Not that hard.  I just don't want to write it from scratch if it already existed, but i'm starting to think it doesn't.. . yet.

Comment: It's more complicated than that. You have to keep track of scope, for one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that minifying javascript using a SP is a good idea. You will end up with something really complex I guess. The simplest minifier that I know is [jsmin](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSMin/blob/master/jsmin.c) and it still 300 lines of C.

Another approach could be to user a minifying proxy as a web server. I guess that it's quite fast (less than 20 lines of code) to come up with something using nodejs and uglifyjs.

Comment: I'll check it out. I like your proxying idea.  If i absolutely have to minify this code, i'll go down that road instead of trying to do it in TSQL.